# Cannot edit post to format code

Tags: feature-request, bug, code-formatting, code, code-only-answers

There has been many posts I have seen with very improper and annoying code formatting. Some code is formatted, some is not, etc. When trying to fix it I get the error:

> "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

I have seen this dozens of times and can not fix it. I think removing this filter for people editing posts (especially those editing posts that need to be approved anyway) would be very helpful. Why should I add detail if I do not know the detail?

Comment: I would imagine that the question is already on the threshold for this check, and the formatting puts it over the line.  Often these questions are not salvageable anyway for reasons other than simply the code formatting.

Comment: So just leave it be?

Comment: If the formatting of the code is one issue in a long list of problems, leave it be, and flag it for moderation.

Answer (score 0):

Going off what Joe C said, I (you) should leave it alone as it is most likely already on the threshold for a check by a moderator and this formatting puts it over the line. He said posts with this formatting are most likely going to be a bad question.

Unless I hear otherwise from a mod I guess I will have to flag it. Flagging it will have mods look at it!

**UPDATE:** When Joe asked me for an example I went to three different posts (all posted 10 minutes or less before) and they were all deleted. This "reinforces the theory"

**UPDATE #2** Bugs said "I'd like to point out that you shouldn't use the custom flag to raise these issues but the other reasons (too broad / unclear / off topic (missing MCVE)). You should only use the custom flag if the community can't deal with it."

Comment: I should point out that this is just an educated guess.  If you have an example, that would be helpful to either confirm this theory, or offer another.

Comment: @JoeC Can not find them although saw them 5-10 minutes ago... Looks like they were deleted ;)

Comment: Will update when I find another.

Comment: That does reinforce the theory, actually.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you shouldn't use the custom flag to raise these issues but the other reasons (too broad / unclear / off topic (missing MCVE)). You should only use the custom flag if the community can't deal with it.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to edit your answer off the back of every comment the community makes.  The rest of the community can read these comments too :)